# Will background fetch be called when app is in background?

Tags: ios, background-fetch

Will iOS call `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` for the running app that is taken to background (using Home button)?

I thought it is only called when iOS launches my app to do background fetch.

If iOS launches `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` even if my app is running in background, then I have one more question:

I need to fetch data from remote server periodically. I now use `NSTimer` and it works even when app is in background. My idea was to use background fetch to do it even if app is not running, but if enable background fetch, I may face situation when my own thread (with `NSTimer`) does some fetching and iOS calls `performFetchWithCompletionHandler`.

So, should I **stop** any timers when my app goes to background and wait for background fetch, then?

Comment: Did you got solution to your issue.
if yes can you please share here which makes helpful to me.

Comment: Did you get the answer?